# Companies Page glitching when scrolling 1 step down

Tags: bug, status-review, design, companies-page

The [*Companies* page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies) on Stack Overflow has a weird bug that makes the page glitch when scrolling with the middle [mouse wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_wheel), one step down. It can't decide between staying on top, or scrolling down.

**Example:** https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/modus-create or any really

**Tested using:** Latest Google Chrome (Incognito - Disabled extensions)

**Sample behavior:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiGYn.jpg

This only happens if you are logged in to an account, otherwise it will scroll downwards without a problem.

Also I tested using the keyboard [down arrow key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_keys) (one click), and it will forever freeze in that state of glitching.

Comment: It also glitches in Firefox. It appears to be due to SE using a `.toggle()` on the class that controls stickiness and size of that `<header>` element. The `.toggle()` is performed when a SE-custom event, `sticky-change`, is fired on the element. I didn't track down what fires the event, but, presumably, it's in a `scroll` event handler and doesn't implement some type of hysteresis, or the hysteresis is too small, such that it just repeatedly fires when the `scrollY` value lands on or passes through the threshold. It could be implemented based on something else, but it's that type of issue.

Comment: My "one step down" is 5 lines, which did not trigger the effect.

Comment: This seemed substantially easier to duplicate, even when not logged in, when the left-nav was disabled. You can go into the browser console and run `StackExchange.topbar.toggleUnpinnedLeftNav()` to toggle the left-nav on and off to see it makes a difference for you (without affecting your left-nav preference setting).

Answer (score -10):

Try to change the Screen Resolution of your PC from Desktop settings.

Comment: I don't think this is a viable work around. Can't keep changing machine wide settings to overcome an issue on one page of a single website.

Comment: My monitor size is 4k, I tested it also on regular HD, the only reason you see the small recording is because I didn't want to upload a 1GB+ file showing something simple :)

Comment: Re *"Desktop settings"*: Referring to Windows? It isn't in [GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) (at least not the version I am using ([GNOME 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_3))) or [LXDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE).